# Performing Select Operation in Linq Using IN Clause/

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string with Names seperated by comma and I need to perform Select Operation Using In clause for the string I have..

here is my Code

```
protected void btnSubmitt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> ids = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < RadListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ids.Add(RadListBox2.Items[i].Text);

            }

            string result = string.Join(",", ids);
            //result I have Data Something like This
            result=name1,name2

            var ProductAttributeRowId = string.Join(",", from m in dt.AsEnumerable() where m.Field<string>("ProductAttributeName") in result  select m.Field<long>("ProductAttributeRowId"));
            string json = "{'ProductRowId':" + hdnId.Value+ ",'ProductAttributeRowId':'" + ProductAttributeRowId +"'}";
            statuslabel.Text = ClsUtility.HttpPost(url + "Services/Product.svc/ProductAttributesID", json);

        }
        catch (Exception Err)
        {
        }
        BindGrid();


    }
```

it shows the error when I used 'in' Linq Query pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Why do you concatenate the ID's with comma if you need to split them two lines behind?

Use `Contains` with the original list, i guess this is what you want:

```
var ProductAttributeRowId = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => ids.Contains(row.Field<string>("ProductAttributeName")))
    .Select(row => row .Field<long>("ProductAttributeRowId"));
```

Comment: it returns ProductAttributeRowId as System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.Int64]'

Comment: @ManoharJonnalagadda: yes, and what's wrong with it?

Comment: need to get the values na like 2, 3

Comment: @ManoharJonnalagadda: you need to execute the query, but you haven't mentioned the desired end-result. If you want a `long[]` append `.ToArray()` if you want a `List<long>` append `.ToList()`, if you want a string with all values separated by comma use `String.Join(",", ProductAttributeRowId)`, if you want to loop them use `foreach(long l in ProductAttributeRowId)...`

Comment: I need to retrieve ProductAttributeRowId  as valus seperated by comma

Comment: something like this                                                                                var ProductAttributeRowId =string.Join(",", from m in dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => ids.Contains(row.Field<string>("ProductAttributeName"))).Select(row => row.Field<long>("ProductAttributeRowId"));

Comment: @ManoharJonnalagadda: have you read my last comment, especially the `String.Join` part- completly?

Answer (score 0):

To perform a IN query, use the following syntax:

```
var array = new List<String>(...);
var contains = (from elm in collection where array.Contains(elm)).Any();
```

That is, you invert the logic: a collection containing values contains your iterator variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ProductAttributeRowId =string.Join("," ,dt.AsEnumerable()
.Where(row => ids.Contains(row.Field<string>("ProductAttributeName")))
.Select(row => row.Field<long>("ProductAttributeRowId")));
```